# Generating GraphQL schema from external .graphqls file in scala (sangria)

Tags: scala, graphql, sangria

In graphql-scala, can we parse and use a graphql schema passed externally in some .graphqls file so that I don't have to create case classes for each of the object types. I know this is very much possible in graphql-java which picks the schema from a .graphqls file where I do not have to create POJOs for each object.
So basically, my requirement is that we would have more than 100 tables, schemas for which would be stored in hbase as key-value pairs in json format for each of the tables. I would have a program which would read the schema from hbase and create a .graphqls file to be then used in my graphQL server.

Comment: https://github.com/muuki88/sbt-graphql

Comment: @sarveshseri, I get "Schema was materialized and cannot be used for any queries except introspection queries." error when I read and build the schema from an external .graphql file and execute it